# SQL server name not getting after installation of SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am not getting SQL server after installation I tried with . I checked SQL server configuration manager not getting correct solution

Comment: What is the /correct solution/ If the instance isn't showing in sql server configuration manager its likely not on the server you are looking at.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at how to ask(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is too broad based to get any support (Write a title that summarizes the specific problem) and you have not showed any research effort of what you have tried (Search, and research!). If you give people a tighter brief they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To find SQL Management studio, search for it in the start menu.

Search for "management studio".

Comment: Not like this actually I have installed SQL server 2008.but I forgot my SQL server name because of that I am unable to login